# Retrofit2 Post and Get Json Array Data with Hashmap

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have written below code in Retrofit2 to Post and Retreive data based on Posted data.It is working perfectly but sometimes it is making some delay on post and receive,can hashmap make it somewhat faster. how can use the hashmap thing for the same to post and retrieve data.Getting No idea

Below is my APIInterface

```
@FormUrlEncoded // annotation used in POST type requests
@POST("/myhippo.php")
    // API's endpoints


Call<SignUpResponse> registration(@Field("umobile") String umobile,
                                        @Field("pickup_lat") String pickup_lat,
                                        @Field("pickup_lan") String pickup_lan,
                                        @Field("drp_lat") String drp_lat,
                                        @Field("drp_lan") String drp_lan,         
                                  );
```

And below I am posting data and receiving the response

```
Api.getClient().registration(umobile,pck_lat,pck_lan,drp_lat,drp_lan).enqueue(new Callback<SignUpResponse>() {

  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call<SignUpResponse> call, Response<SignUpResponse> response) {

    log.e(response.body().getUmobile());)
  }
```

And this is my SignUpResponse.java

```
private String pickup_lan;
private String drp_lat;
private String drp_lan;

public String getPickup_lat() {
    return pickup_lat;
}

public void setPickup_lat(String pickup_lat) {
    this.pickup_lat = pickup_lat;
}

public String getPickup_lan() {
    return pickup_lan;
}

public void setPickup_lan(String pickup_lan) {
    this.pickup_lan = pickup_lan;
}

public String getDrp_lat() {
    return drp_lat;
}

public void setDrp_lat(String drp_lat) {
    this.drp_lat = drp_lat;
}

public String getDrp_lan() {
    return drp_lan;
}

public void setDrp_lan(String drp_lan) {
    this.drp_lan = drp_lan;
}
```

And this is my Api

```
public class Api {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
public static ApiInterface2 getClient() {

    // change your base URL
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://baseurl.website/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    //Creating object for our interface
    ApiInterface api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    return api; // return the APIInterface object
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that it can help increase the speed, but this is the way to send data as a map

```
Call<SignUpResponse> registration(@FieldMap Map<String,String> map);
```

collect the data like this

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("pickup_lat","8512397");
    .
    .
    .
```